# Do promoted siege-minions intercept champion-targeted projectiles?

Tags: league-of-legends

Some projectiles that target champions can be intercepted by his allies to safe the target, e.g. Caitlyns `Ace in the Hole` and Ashes `Enchanted Crystal Arrow`.
From my understanding normal minions are simply too small and those projectiles fly over their heads. But when siege minions are promoted they get much bigger, would they intercept such projectiles or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on which side you are on) not !

These projectiles are cast and only hit champions, promoted aren't champions.

To be noticed that, on the other side, all clones from champions (Mord's ult, Yorick's ult, Shaco's ult, leblanc's passiv) are considered champions and intercept correctly these spells.